# How do I set a default value for my .onchange function and still keep the 'onchange' functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a custom search application showing results of a user input. In the application I have included a way for the user to control the amount of results that display.

**HTML**

```
<select id="countShow">
    <option selected="selected">10</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>100</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("select").on('change', function () {
    $('#countShow').val(10);
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
    str = $(this).text();
    str = parseInt(str) - 1;
});
    $('div > #result:gt('+str+')').remove();
    console.log(str);
})
```

My `console.log` shows the original value as 10 when the page loads and I understand that it is waiting for the control to change.

I have tried adding the following before the function to create a default value:

```
$('#countShow').val(10); //the value stays 10 and will not change on event
$('div > #result:gt(9)').remove(); //does the same as the first
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can call it on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").trigger('change');
});
```

trigger simulates the change event on loading the page

Comment: supposes seems a weird way to clarify this, simulates is better imho

Comment: @DarkBee, Thanks. Revised